# What header files should i include in order to use limit_d directive in boost spirit?

Tags: c++, parsing, boost-spirit

I am a beginner in using `boost spirit`.

What I want to do is just parse a text that has a time in the following format:

> HH:MM::SS

and that is pretty easy by using the following rule (boost documentation)

```
uint_parser<int, 10, 2, 2> uint2_p;

r = lexeme_d
    [
        boost::spirit::limit_d(0u, 23u)[uint2_p] >> ':' 
        >>  boost::spirit::limit_d(0u, 59u)[uint2_p] >> ':' 
        >>  boost::spirit::limit_d(0u, 59u)[uint2_p]           
    ];
```

The problem is that I am getting a compiler error stating that `limit_d` is not a member of `boost spirit` namespace, even though `limit_d` directive is located under `boost::spirit` namespace in the following header:

> boost/spirit/home/classic/core/composite/directives.hpp

And I have included this header.

So I have got confused about which header should I include in order the get the code compile (I am using VS2013)

P.S. My code is working correctly without `limit_d` directive so the problem is definitely caused by  `limit_d`.

Comment: From [this](http://boost-spirit.com/old_docs/v1_6/doc/directives.html) example they are calling it without qualifying the name.

Comment: ...and if you had posted a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) I could've looked at what it does different to my working productive code, and wrote up the diff in an answer. Since you didn't bother to *write* a MCVE, I don't really feel like turning *my* code into a MCVE either. You see how this works?

Comment: thanks @NathanOliver  for correcting the mistakes.
I know that the example calling it without qualifying the name, however I have tried that and the compile error has changed to " 'limit_d': identifier not found"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the answer posted by @DevSolar I can see `limit_d` but that will introduce another compile error stating that we can't use

```
boost::spirit::qi::uint_parser<int, 10, 2, 2> uint2_p;
```

with `limit_d` so I changed that to

```
boost::spirit::classic::uint_parser<uint16, 10, 2, 2> uint2_p;
```

As a result the time parser rule will be as follow:

```
boost::spirit::classic::uint_parser<uint16, 10, 2, 2>           uint2_p;
boost::spirit::qi::rule<std::string::const_iterator, Time(), qi::space> Time_;

Time_ = lexeme_d
    [
            boost::spirit::classic::limit_d(0u, 23u)[uint2_p] >> ':'
        >>  boost::spirit::classic::limit_d(0u, 59u)[uint2_p] >> ':'
        >>  boost::spirit::classic::limit_d(0u, 59u)[uint2_p]
    ];
```

the problem with this code is that we can't use `limit_d` with `Boost::Spirit::QI` as you have noticed that the rule from QI namespace.

So I have searched for a `limit_d` equivalent which is compatible with Spirit 2.x

As stated [here](http://lists.boost.org/boost-users/2010/07/60965.php), there is no equivalent for `limit_d`in Spirit 2.x and instead you have to use semantic action which is a solution for my problem.

So the working code should look like this:

```
    namespace qi = boost::spirit::qi;
    struct Time
    {
        unsigned Hour;
        unsigned Minute;
        unsigned Second;
    };

    boost::spirit::qi::rule<std::string::const_iterator, Time(), qi::space> Time_;

    Time_ = lexeme_d
        [
                    qi::uint_[qi::_pass = (0 <= qi::_1 && qi::_1 <= 23)] >> ':'
                >>  qi::uint_[qi::_pass = (0 <= qi::_1 && qi::_1 <= 59)] >> ':'
                >>  qi::uint_[qi::_pass = (0 <= qi::_1 && qi::_1 <= 59)]
        ];
```

Answer (score 3):

You are [supposed](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/spirit/doc/html/spirit/structure/include.html) to use the headers in `<boost/spirit/include/...>`, so that Boost may shift around their internals without affecting client code.

The include `<boost/spirit/include/classic_directives.hpp>` is merely a wrapper around the one *you* used, however, so there is nothing wrong with your header aside from ignoring one layer of abstraction.

**The real issue is the *namespace* you used** -- `boost::spirit` -- vs. the one you *should* have used -- `boost::spirit::classic`.

IIRC, they shifted the former `boost::spirit` into `boost::spirit::classic` several versions back, when the new Spirit v2 API came out and they tried to fix the Spirit ["Header Hell"](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/spirit/doc/html/spirit/faq.html#spirit.faq.i_m_very_confused_about_the_header_hell_in_my_boost_spirit_directory__what_s_all_this_about_).

```
#include <boost/spirit/include/classic_directives.hpp>

namespace bspirit = boost::spirit::classic;

int main()
{
    bspirit::limit_d( 0u, 23u );
}
```

If you're not afraid of the higher compile time and don't want to figure out which header to use *exactly*, you could of course simply `#include <boost/spirit/include/classic.hpp>` and be done with it. ;-)

Comment: Orrrrr just use a version of the library that was supported somewhere in the last decade :) "Several versions ago" is a bit of a misnomer. It think it's ~20  versions ago.

Comment: @sehe: If I hadn't taken drastic measures, personally, my company would *still* insist that one of our products use ICU 3.6 and Boost 1.34.1, because "that's what we tested". :-D